# Perl dancer: Passing rows of database info to template

Tags: perl, dbi, dancer

Using the info from tutorial I created a method which takes info from the form and checks what is available in the database for the entered data:

```
post '/identry' => sub {
#to cut short the long code the following are the steps
#getting the last time the data has been entered into the database
# to match with the ids entered through the form , I have to display what is available
   in the database for the same position
   my $sql2 = "SELECT a.ID FROM db_test a, db_check b  WHERE 
 a.POSITION=b.RACK||'/'||b.POS AND DOE =TO_TIMESTAMP('$last_entry','dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss:ff') ORDER BY SUBSTR(a.POSITION,9,3)";

    my $sth2= $dbh->prepare($sql2) or die $dbh->errstr;
    $sth2->execute() or die "$dbh->errstr \n";
    template 'checkid.tt', {
        'checkid_url' => uri_for('/checkid'),
         'entries' => $sth2->fetchall_hashref('ID'),
         };
};
```

I am getting the error

```
 Warning caught during route execution: DBD::Oracle::st fetchall_hashref failed: ERROR no statement executing (perhaps you need to call execute first) [for Statement "SELECT a.ID FROM db_test a,db_check b  WHERE a.POSITION=b.RACK||'/'||b.POS AND DOE =TO_TIMESTAMP('02-12-2014 12:00:33:000000','dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss:ff') ORDER BY SUBSTR(a.POSITION,9,3)"]
```

The template is as follows

```
<% IF entries.size %>
   <% FOREACH ID IN entries %>
       <p><input type="text" name=id1 id="id1" value="<% entries.$ID.0 %>" size =8>
          <input type="text" name=id2 id="id2" value="<% entries.$ID.1 %>" size =8>
       </p>
   <% END %>
<% ELSE %>
 <em> No data available in Database </em>
<% END %>
```

Comment: Can you log $sth2->{Executed} after the `->execute`? Also note that methods are not interpolated in double quotes (`"$dbh->errstr"`).

Comment: I have dumed the results using data::Dumper after the execute on fetchall_hashref                                                        `my $entries = $sth2->fetchall_hashref('ID');
  print STDERR Dumper($entries);` and getting the result as follows      `$VAR1 ={001A => {'ID' =>'001A'},'002b => {'ID' =>'002b'}};`

Comment: Hm... can you than pass `entries => $entries` to the template?

Comment: Its still the same error

Comment: Is there a b.Id?  Maybe try fetchall_hashref('a.ID')?

Comment: There is a b.id , i have given alias for a.id. Also i tired without the alias, still its giving me error.

Comment: Hi regarding the same one i am able to pass it through the template but getting the output Dancer::Route=HASH(0x3583978). is ithere something wrong with templating?

Answer (score 0):

You are not selecting other columns from the table. Do you want to select ID only?
If not, include other columns in your select query.

In the template, fetch values inside the foreach loop like below:

```
<input type="text" name=id1 id="id1" value="<% entries.$ID.ID %>" size =8>
<input type="text" name=id1 id="id1" value="<% entries.$ID.OTHERCOLUMN %>" size =8>
```

When you are using column names keep in mind its case sensitive.(FYI)

Also practice using aliases for every column in the query: